# Firbase/Heroku/Node JS - Firebase Invalid Credential / failed to parse service account json file / ENAMETOOLONG

Tags: node.js, firebase, github, heroku, firebase-admin

I'm using github actions to deploy my first webapp via Heroku.

My code:

```
const fireBaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin');

if (!fireBaseAdmin) 
  throw new Error('The FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS environment variable was not found!');

fireBaseAdmin.initializeApp({
  "credential": fireBaseAdmin.credential.cert(JSON.stringify({
    "type": process.env.FIREBASE_TYPE,
    "project_id": process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    "private_key_id": process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID,
    "private_key": process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
    "client_email": process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    "client_id": process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_ID,
    "auth_uri": process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_URI,
    "token_uri": process.env.FIREBASE_TOKEN_URI,
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_PROVIDER,
    "client_x509_cert_url": process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT
  }))
});

module.exports = fireBaseAdmin;
```

Each of the .env variables are stored in Heroku's Config Vars.

Error log from Heroku (I stripped sensitive tokens/keys):

```
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818119+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential-internal.js:151
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818149+00:00 app[web.1]: throw new error_1.FirebaseAppError(error_1.AppErrorCodes.INVALID_CREDENTIAL, 'Failed to parse service account json file: ' + error);
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818150+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818150+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818166+00:00 app[web.1]: FirebaseAppError: Failed to parse service account json file: Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open '{
"type":"service_account",
"project_id":"ec31",
"private_key_id":"2900d",
"private_key":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nQ=\n-----END\nPRIVATE KEY-----\n",
"client_email":"firebase-adminsdk-.gserviceaccount.com",
"client_id":"10",
"auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"ttps://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
"client_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-o.gserviceaccount.com"
}'
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818167+00:00 app[web.1]: at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28)
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818168+00:00 app[web.1]: at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:90:28)
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818168+00:00 app[web.1]: at new FirebaseAppError (/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:125:28)
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818169+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.ServiceAccount.fromPath (/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential-internal.js:151:19)
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818169+00:00 app[web.1]: at new ServiceAccountCredential (/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential-internal.js:67:28)
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818174+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.exports.cert (/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential.js:34:54)
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818174+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/firebase/index.js:25:42)
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818175+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818175+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818175+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818176+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818176+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818177+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818177+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/middlewares/auth.js:1:15)
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818177+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818178+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10) {
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818178+00:00 app[web.1]: errorInfo: {
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818178+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'app/invalid-credential',
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818190+00:00 app[web.1]: message: `Failed to parse service account json file: Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open '{
"type":"service_account",
"project_id":"e1",
"private_key_id":"2900",
"private_key":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMIIEMoQ=\\n-----END\\nPRIVATE KEY-----\\n",
"client_email":"firebase-adminsdk-od.gserviceaccount.com",
"client_id":"1",
"auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"ttps://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
"client_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-o.gserviceaccount.com"
}'`
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818190+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818190+00:00 app[web.1]: codePrefix: 'app'
2021-08-17T11:16:53.818191+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-08-17T11:16:53.947406+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-08-17T11:16:54.345497+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I've been attempted to update my code based on the various posts on Stack Overflow but I'm not having success with solving the error. Here's a short list of the post I've been referencing:

[Deploying Firebase App with Service Account to Heroku (environment variables with dotenv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287108/deploying-firebase-app-with-service-account-to-heroku-environment-variables-wit)
[Authenticating with the Firebase Admin SDK using environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48834843/authenticating-with-the-firebase-admin-sdk-using-environment-variable)
[Node.js -Firebase Service Account Private Key won't parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299329/node-js-firebase-service-account-private-key-wont-parse)
[Firebase: Failed to parse service account: 'project_id' must be set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148808/firebase-failed-to-parse-service-account-project-id-must-be-set)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cert()` method expects either the path to `serviceAccount.json` file (string) or a `ServiceAccount` object. Here you are entering a string so it's expecting that to be the path to `serviceAccount.json` and not stringified credentials and hence you get the error `FirebaseAppError: Failed to parse service account json file`. Try this:

```js
fireBaseAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    type: process.env.FIREBASE_TYPE,
    project_id: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    private_key_id: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID,
    private_key: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
    client_email: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    client_id: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_ID,
    auth_uri: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_URI,
    token_uri: process.env.FIREBASE_TOKEN_URI,
    auth_provider_x509_cert_url: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_PROVIDER,
    client_x509_cert_url: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT
  }),
  databaseURL: `https://${process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}.firebaseio.com/`
})
```

Comment: thanks for such a quick response! I made your suggested changes and included:                                                                                                                                            const admin = require('firebase-admin')                                                                              
Im now receiving the following error:                                                         
FirebaseAppError: Failed to parse private key: Error: Invalid PEM formatted message.

Comment: it did not work but I think we are getting closer! I now have an invalid PEM formatting message

Comment: @golembeskia I would try `console.log(process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'))` and check if it is similar to the key as in downloaded service account JSON

Comment: I regenerated the private_key on Firebase and now everything is working.